# In-app purchases when the country is not supported?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

I'm a developer from Jordan and sadly Jordan is not listed in googles [Supported locations for merchants](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/150324) so this means I can't deploy my in-app purchases on android. I was wondering if there is any work-around for the situation I'm facing?

Can I for example open an overseas bank account and use that as reference? Or use the bank account of a friend that lives in a supported country?

Comment: Just as a clarification for the downvoters, I saw other similar threads on stackoverflow but they all suggested alternative stores to the google play, I couldn't find a thread where something like an overseas bank account were discussed.

Comment: hi, there I am wandering if you have resolved your issue, can we use purchase inside my app but the item we sell is from a different country (google account) ?? please help